# Advise Request: How to launch three .bat files at the same time?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I got three separate .bat files. Each has the following three commands respectively.

```
    file1.bat:     cmd /K "cd C:\PythonScripts\X3865\ & python run_all.py"
    file1.bat:     cmd /K "cd C:\PythonScripts\X3865_1\ & python run_all.py"
    file1.bat:     cmd /K "cd C:\PythonScripts\X3865_2\ & python run_all.py"
```

Currently to execute the program, I go to the Windows file folder and double click on each of them to launch the programs. They come up in three different command windows.

I want to combine the above commands in 1 single .bat file, which when executed will launch all the three programs automatically. How can I do this?

Comment: The provided answers will run the three python scripts sequentially. It's not clear whether that's what you want, or if you want to run all three in parallel (simultaneously).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers from **Mark** and **ian0411** will run the three python scripts one after the other. If that's what you want, go with either of those. If you want to run the three scripts simultaneously, your batch file should be

```
start cmd /c python "c:\pythonscripts\x3865\run_all.py"
start cmd /c python "c:\pythonscripts\x3865_1\run_all.py"
start cmd /c python "c:\pythonscripts\x3865_2\run_all.py"
```

This will start each in a separate window; if there is output that is needed from the command(s), change the `/c` to `/k`; this will leave the window open until you close it manually.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I needed to run all three programs in parallel. So this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This should run the Python scripts in order:

```
python "C:\PythonScripts\X3865\run_all.py"
python "C:\PythonScripts\X3865_1\run_all.py"
python "C:\PythonScripts\X3865_2\run_all.py"
```

Their outputs will all be printed to the same cmd window. If you wish to see the outputs at the end, add `pause` to the end of the bat file so that it won't automatically close.

Answer (score 0):

Save the following into a `.bat` file

```
python "C:\PythonScripts\X3865\run_all.py"
python "C:\PythonScripts\X3865_1\run_all.py"
python "C:\PythonScripts\X3865_2\run_all.py"
```

And then just run that `.bat` file and it should do it.